# Are there any tools to convert an Iphone localized string file to a string resources file that can be used in Android?

Tags: android, localization, port

I have the localized strings file that is used in the Iphone app that I work on to port to Android. Are there any tools that go through the file taken from the xcode project and build the xml needed to use the strings in android?

As the apple file is a simple key value file is there a tool that converts string in this format

> "key"="value"

to this:

`<string name="key"> value </string>`

This tool should be easy to build but I appreciate any pointers to already working tools.

Comment: you should be able to accomplish this with some XSLT magic...

Comment: That "magic" would only apply in the opposite problem (from Android XML files, to flat iPhone text files). XSLT can only convert from XML to XML/TEXT/HTML. He is out of luck this time.

Comment: @Jenusz i have get the same requirment,kindly can you guide me that how i can acheive this?if u have any sample code then please send me on farhanshah_1987@yahoo.com,also +1 from me..thanks

Comment: this is my posted question please checkedhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382277/android-how-to-convert-ios-strings-file-to-android-xml-through-programmatically

Comment: @Janusz twine can be used https://github.com/mobiata/twine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i wrote my own little converter using a little bit from the code from alex.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner fileScanner =
            new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]), "utf-16");
    Writer writer =
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(args[1])), "UTF8"));
    writer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> <resources>");
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        if (line.contains("=")) {
            line = line.trim();
            line = line.replace("\"", "");
            line = line.replace(";", "");
            String[] parts = line.split("=");
            String nextLine =
                    "<string name=\"" + parts[0].trim() + "\">"
                            + parts[1].trim() + "</string>";
            System.out.println(nextLine);
            writer.append(nextLine);
        }
    }
    fileScanner.close();
    writer.append("</resources>");
    writer.close();
}
```

It was a little bit tricky to get Java to correctly read and write the UTF 16 input I got out of the xcode project but now it is working like a charm.

Comment: It works, but I strongly encourage learning the command line tools you have available to you. In my opinion, things like this are so much easier if you can write one or two lines on the command line rather than making a new Java program for every itch you need to scratch.

Comment: It depends on what I want to do and which language I'm fastest in. I thought about doing it in python because it is task suitable for a nice scripting language but I was faster doing it in Java at the moment.

Answer (score 9):

I think you might like this tool :

http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/files/stringsconvert.html

Also this one, but it lacks some features (like converting whitespace in name) :

http://localise.biz/free/converter/ios-to-android

It is free, no need of registration, and you won't need to build your own script!

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the areas where the Unix mindset and toolset comes in handy. I don't know what the iPhone format is like, but if it's what you say, with each value one per line, a simple `sed` call could do this:

```
$ cat infile
"key"="value"
"key2"="value2"
$ sed 's/ *"\([^"]*\)" *= *"\([^"]*\)"/<string name="\1">\2<\/string>/' infile
<string name="key">value</string>
<string name="key2">value2</string>
$
```

I expect sed is available on your OSX install.

Answer (score 4):

I improved your main method above to work for me:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringsConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]), "utf-16");
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(args[1])), "UTF8"));
        writer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<resources>\n");
        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
            if (line.contains("=")) {               
                String[] parts = line.split("=");

                parts[0] = parts[0].trim()
                    .replace(" ", "_")
                    .replace("\\n", "_")
                    .replace("-", "_")
                    .replace("\"", "")
                    .replace(";", "")
                    .replace("'", "")
                    .replace("/", "")
                    .replace("(", "")
                    .replace(")", "")
                    .replace("?", "_Question");

                parts[1] = parts[1].trim().substring(1, parts[1].length()-3);
                parts[1] = parts[1].replace("'", "\\'");

                String nextLine = "<string name=\"" + parts[0] + "\">" + parts[1].trim() + "</string>";
                System.out.println(nextLine);
                writer.append(nextLine + "\n");
            }
        }
        fileScanner.close();
        writer.append("</resources>");
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: add this line too parts[1] = parts[1].replace("&", "&amp;");

Answer (score 3):

The "tool" I've used to convert a Java properties file:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream("c:/messages_en.properties"), "utf-8"));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        if (line.length() > 0) {
            String[] parts = line.split(" = ");
            System.out.println("<string name=\"" + parts[0] + "\">"
                    + parts[1] + "</string>");
        }
    }
    br.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Added few modification to above solutions:

- Android styled string names - lowercase worlds, separated by "_";
- Convert iOS string format arguments to java format (%@, %@ to %1$s, %2$s ...)
- Convert comments;

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner fileScanner =
            new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]), "utf-16");
    Writer writer =
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(args[1])), "UTF8"));
    writer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<resources>");
    writer.append("\n");
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        if (line.contains("="))
        {
            line = line.trim();
            line = line.replace("\"", "");
            line = line.replace(";", "");
            String[] parts = line.split("=");
            String resultName = processName(parts[0]);
            String resultValue = processValue(parts[1]);
            String nextLine =
                    "<string name=\"" + resultName.toLowerCase() + "\">"
                            + resultValue + "</string>";
            System.out.println(nextLine);
            writer.append(nextLine);
            writer.append("\n");
        } else
        {

            line = line.replace("/*", "<!--");
            line = line.replace("*/", "-->");
            writer.append(line);
            writer.append("\n");
        }
    }
    fileScanner.close();
    writer.append("</resources>");
    writer.close();
}

private static String processValue(String part)
{
    String value = part.trim();
    StringBuilder resultValue = new StringBuilder();
    if (value.contains("%@"))
    {
        int formatCnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = value.charAt(i);
            char next = value.length() > i + 1 ? value.charAt(i + 1) : '\0';
            if (c == '%' && next == '@')
            {
                formatCnt++;
                resultValue.append('%');
                resultValue.append(formatCnt);
                resultValue.append("$s");
                i++;
            } else
            {
                resultValue.append(value.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }   else{
        resultValue.append(value);
    }
    return resultValue.toString();
}

private static String processName(String part)
{
    String name = part.trim();
    name = name.replace(" ", "_");
    name = name.replace("-", "_");
    name = name.replace("\n", "_");
    name = name.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 _]", "");
    if (Character.isDigit(name.charAt(0)))
    {
        name = "_" + name;
    }
    StringBuilder resultName = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = name.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
        {
            char prev = i > 0 ? name.charAt(i - 1) : '\0';
            if (prev != '_' && !Character.isUpperCase(prev) && prev != '\0')
            {
                resultName.append('_');
            }
            resultName.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));


        } else
        {
            resultName.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
        }
    }
    return resultName.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This don't really answer your question, but you may consider DMLocalizedString for your future iOS+Android project. Currently the source is for iOS only, but I believe that making the Android version is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

For converting to **Android**, use my regex code. You can test it online (copy the replacement string):

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6dA

regex used is `^"(.*)"\s=\s"(.*)";$/m` , replacement string is `<string name="$1">$2</string>`

For converting to **iOS**, use my regex code (copy the replacement string):

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6dC

regex used is `^\<string name=\"(.*)\"\>(.*)\<\/string\>/m` , replacement string is `"$1" = "$2";`

Answer (score 0):

Web based online converter (both ways):
https://gunhansancar.com/tools/converter/